# Can not upload some image file in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, upload

My wordpress site can upload image, but I don't know why I can not upload below file in my server. I installed my site in another site and I can upload.
In current server, I can upload other file but only below file, when I upload it displays that HTTP Error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsqtC.jpg

Comment: Is any errors are showing

Comment: only display HTTP Error 403 Forbidden

Comment: Screenshot please

Comment: https://imgur.com/6godBtW

Comment: @Tristup I don't know reason. I can upload any photo but https://imgur.com/yfTSGnX I can not upload this photo

Comment: @Tristup if I edit this file by Paint tool and save it. I can upload it

Comment: https://en.support.wordpress.com/images/adding-images-to-posts-or-pages/